# Macにおけるbash等コンソール出力の日本語化

Tags: bash, macos, centos

現在、Mac OSXとCentOSの2つの環境が手元にあります。

Mac上でbashを動かしている時、例えば次のように無効なコマンドを打つと、英語でその旨が表示されます。

```
$ hello
bash: hello: command not found
```

一方、CentOS上で同じコマンドを打った時、次のように日本語で表示されます。

```
$ hello
-bash: hello: コマンドが見つかりません
```

これ以外でもcpコマンドやrmコマンドなどの出力が日本語で表示されます。

Macでも同様に日本語表示出来るのでしょうか？

Comment: OSX のターミナルで `echo $LC_ALL` を実行すると何が表示されますか？

Comment: @heliac2001 「ja_JP.UTF-8」です。CentOSの方も同様です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。そうしますと、OSX には `/usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/bash.mo` というファイルがないか、もしくは英語版の bash.mo へのシンボリックリンクになっているのかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://translationproject.org/PO-files/ja/
からバージョンに合ったpoファイルを取ってきて、それを`msgfmt`コマンドでmoファイルに変換したファイルを`/usr/share/locale/ja/LC_MESSAGES/`に置くことで日本語化出来ました。

<strike>ただ、こういう事を自動でやってくれるようなツール類はMacには無さそうです。</strike>
MacPorts の bash は自動で日本語化されるんですね。 @heliac2001 さん、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

MacPortsのbashを入れているからか日本語表示になってます。
言語関連の環境変数は特に設定していません。

Comment: 元々入っているbashやHomebrewのみ見て判断していました。ありがとうございます。